# How to create a collection/array in size N with each cell initialized to zero in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Is there a short way to create a collection/array in size N with each cell initialized to zero in Groovy? Can't seem to find it on http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections

For example

```
arr = func(3)
```

would result in

```
arr = [0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yep, the [`Collection#multiply`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#multiply%28java.lang.Number%29) (or `*`) method:

```
assert [0] * 3 == [0, 0, 0]
```